# A method with return type void and having an empty return , will Response.Redirect(,false) still continue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redirect

```
private void OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            DispatcherInternal.HttpRewriteUrl(l_uri);
            //Will code continue here ?
        }
        internal static void HttpRewriteUrl(string url)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("URL", false);
            return; //Is this a return statement or does the context end
        }
```

Seeing the above code , will the code still continue after rewrite or will it redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code in `OnBeginRequest` will continue running even after calling `HttpRewriteUrl`.

The `return` in `HttpRewriteUrl` will only cause that method to return itself. It will not cause the calling method, `OnBeginRequest`, to return as well, unless you explicitly tell it to.

You can confirm this behavior by placing a breakpoint on the line calling `HttpRewriteUrl`, and running your program in debug mode to step through each line.